# Adding multiple percentages to value

Tags: percentages

Good morning,

Apologies if this question seems obvious but I need a little help with adding multiple percentages to a value.

The value: $590,568$
The percentages: $14.62%, 49.068%,  2%$

My understanding is as follows:

$\frac{14.62 }{ 100 }= 0.1462$

$590,568 \times 0.1462 = 86,341.0416$

$\frac{49.068 }{ 100 }= 0.49068$

$590,568 \times 0.49068 = 289,779.90624$

$\frac{2 }{100} = 0.02$

$590,568 \times 0.02 = 11,811.36$

$590,568 + 86,341.0416 + 289,779.90624 + 11,811.36 = 387,932.30784 $

$590,568 + 387,932.30784 = 978,500.30784$

My question is if this is correct or should I be multiplying each percentage (after it's been divided by $100$) by the new total so e.g. ($590,568 + 86,341.0416) \times 49.068$

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please state the precise problem statement. "Adding multiple percentages" is an ambiguous formulation.

Comment: Thank you Jośe. Apologies Christoph does the example not help?

Comment: The question you are asking is precisely the ambiguity in the phrase "adding multiple percentages". So no, it doesn't help.

Comment: I think Christoph's point is that unless we see the original questions we cannot tell what was intended. "Adding multiple percentages" could mean add them consecutively to the same base (as you have done in the example) or it could mean compounding the percentages. Without seeing the wording of the original question, we cannot tell.

Comment: So your question is: Should you add ($+$) or multiply ($\times$) percentages? Both are possible to do, and what you should do depends on the context. They represent different things and give different answers. In the current state of the question, it's not entirely clear which one should be used.

Comment: Oh I see. There is no original question it was just my curiosity of how to achieve this.I was under the impression there was only 1 way to add percentages to a value. I'm a programmer but unfortunately the math side is not my strong suit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did well.

You can also think of it like this: all of those percentages are going to be portions of the same quantity (590,568), so you can add them together first $$14.62\% + 49.068\% + 2\% = 65.688\%$$

then you take the 65.688% of 590,568 (which is 590,568*0.65688 = 387,932.3) and that's the amount that you need to add: $$590,568 + 387,932.3 = 978,500.3$$

Comment: Thank you so much.